# Microsoft Remote Desktop local redirection?

Tags: macos, network, remote-desktop

I have a Windows 7 Virtual Machine setup, that I remote into using my Macbook Pro. I'm using Microsoft Remote Desktop 2014, and have Folder Redirection setup. I don't see where the redirected folders are supposed to show up on my VM? It should be a folder called Projects. Screenshot below shows no redirected folders:

[image: Redirection setup]
[image: VM view]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It should show up under **Devices with Removable Storage**.  When you add the folder in Remote Desktop try clicking browse when adding the folder and confirm its the right path to the projects folder.

Comment: I added the folder again, and didn't show up still on my VM. I had it correct before. Don't know what to do :(

Comment: It's showing up now, updated permissions on a fresh VM